# JavaScript recursive array to select html elements

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm currently trying to make a recursive function that takes html elements as an array so I can take html elements like the querySelector function

The reason i'm doing this is because I can't use getElementsByTagName() or querySelector()

Here is my code:

```
function flatten(items) 
{
    const flat = [];
    items.forEach(item => {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            flat.push(...flatten(item));
          } 
          else {
            flat.push(item);
        }
    });
    return flat;
}

var button = flatten(footer).flatten(div);
count = 0;

button.onclick = function() {
    count += 1;
    button.innerHTML = count;
};
```

I get the following error: ReferenceError: footer is not defined

Thanks

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <footer>
            <div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

footer is defined in my HTML, I want to select footer in my function
Also, I can't add class or id to my html, I can't edit it

Comment: What is `footer`? You don't define it anywhere...

Comment: As error says: footer is not defined

Comment: *I get the following error: ReferenceError: footer is not defined* That makes sense, given that... um... `footer` is not defined. (At least not in the code you include in your question.)

Comment: footer is defined in my HTML

Comment: @XavierDeRosnay JavaScript does not know what's defined in your HTML unless you say to go look for it by means of jQuery or the like. Please include your HTML code in the question.

Comment: @SBylemans I can't use jQuery, I updated the question with my HTML code.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why can't you use `getElementsByTagName()`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I lost a bet

Comment: Well, after you've resolved how to get a reference to an HTML element following whatever rules are laid out in your bet, your next problem will be that your code really doesn't do anything that remotely resembles flattening out a structure of HTML elements.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen How do I make it select an HTML element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for the sake of practice (or a lost bet), you'd want to write your own `querySelectorAll`, you *could* write a recursive function that walks the DOM tree... The only thing you rely on is an *entrance* to the DOM: `window.document`.

<sub>Note that this will never be able to compete with the performance of your browser's default query implementations. We're just doing it to show we can.</sub>

---

### Step 1: recursively walking the `document` (depth-first)

```js
const walk = (el) => {
  console.log(el.nodeName);
  Array.from(el.children).forEach(walk);
};


walk(document);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <footer>
            <div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, this function loops over each element in the `document` and its `children`.

### Step 2: Adding the filter logic

If you want it to actually *find* and return elements, you'll have to pass some sort of filtering logic. `querySelectorAll` works with string inputs, which you could try to recreate... Since we're redoing this for fun, our `select` will work with functions of `HTMLElement -> bool`.

```js
const selectIn = (pred, el, result = []) => {
  if (pred(el)) result.push(el);
  
  Array.from(el.children)
    .filter(e => e)
    .map(el2 => selectIn(pred, el2, result));
  
  return result;
}


// EXAMPLE APP
// Define some selectors
const withClass = className => el => 
  el && el.classList && el.classList.contains(className);
  
const withTag = tagName => el =>
  el && el.nodeName === tagName.toUpperCase();

// Select some elements
const footer = selectIn(withTag("footer"), document)[0];
const container = selectIn(withClass("container"), document)[0];
const divsInFooter = selectIn(withTag("div"), footer);

// Log the results
console.log(`
  footer:
${footer.outerHTML}

  container: 
${container.outerHTML}

  divsInFooter:
${divsInFooter.map(d => d.outerHTML)}
`);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><div class="container"><footer><div></div></footer></div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you're the best! The answer was clear and now I understand